# GPU drivers for Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card

I bought a MSI HD 5450 graphic card for my Windows 8.1 PC and there are no drivers on MSI site for this card not only for Windows 8.1, but not even for Windows 8.
Can I install drivers from from AMD site (will they be fully functional) or I should try to find drivers for specific brand of GPU?
Also can I install drivers for Windows 8 on Windows 8.1?

Comment: I had no problem finding drivers for this [card](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Windows%208.1%20-%2064).  **This makes me wonder if you even looked**  You should only download display drivers from your desktop/laptop OEM or your GPU ( AMD/NVidia ) this has been the case for almost a decade.  **Windows Update would have also offered the same AMD display drivers.**

Comment: I found it on AMD site but not on MSI. I thought it's recommended to use drivers from manufacturer's site

Comment: The disk MSI provides in the box, is their OEM software to say overclock the card, and the AMD drivers supplied to them by AMD.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's a locked-down laptop, just use the generic ones from AMD - http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

Comment: In general which drivers are better; from manufacturer's website or AMD\Nvidia?

Comment: for desktop graphics cards, AMD/NVidia/(Intel). it's only on lappies that they are sometimes locked down to specific manufacturer's drivers... which means you're stuck once they can no longer be bothered updating them, about 6 months after you buy the lappy :-(  Windows Update almost *never* has up to date drivers, that would be my least favourite source.

Comment: The MSI's drivers are AMD's drivers supplied to them by AMD.  MSI doesn't write their own drivers, never have, the have always supplied Nvidia and AMD's own drivers.